# If lim x→0 f(x) exists, then lim x→0 f(x) > 0.”

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Show that the following claim is false with a counterexample:
“Let f be a function with domain R. Assume that ∀x ∈ R, f(x) > 0. If lim
x→0
f(x)
exists, then lim
x→0
f(x) > 0.”

Do i negate this and then prove it?

and how can i fix it to be true

Comment: Let $f(x) = |x|$.  Then $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, and $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0 \not> 0$.

Comment: $f(0) = 0$ , and its no bigger than $0$ for all $x$

Comment: it seems that the lack of continuity is what makes a counterexample possible. So ensuring $f$ is continuous (at least at 0) along with strict positivity should make the statement true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's wrong.

A counterexample:

$f(x)=|x|$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=1$.

We see that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=0$.